# willSet and didSet not called for observers on an inherited property

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code in a subclass of UISlider:

```
//`value` is a property of the `UISlider` class that stores the current value of the slider
override var value: Float {
    willSet {
        print("willSet called")
    }
    didSet {
        print("didSet called")
    }
}
```

I have another print statement that prints the value of the `value` field as the slider is dragged. The `value` field is clearly changing because the value for it that's being printed changes as I drag it around, but the property observers are never called. Any idea how the field can change, and yet the property observers are never called?

Comment: Is the above code actually inside the `UISlider` subclass? Are you sure you are actually using the subclass and not `UISlider`?

Comment: @rmaddy yes i'm sure

Comment: How are you sure? Update your question with how you actually use this subclass. And show relevant code showing that this overridden property is in the subclass being used.